# Slow MySQL UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I have a mysql table containing 400,000 rows

whenever I run a PHP script to update one row, it takes about 3-4 seconds to do it.

How can I optimize the update query?

```
UPDATE `weakvocab` SET `times` = times+1, `wrong` = wrong+1, `mtime` = 1284369979 WHERE `owner` = 'owner_name' AND `vocID` = 'ID_number' AND `type` = 'type_name';
```

This query is about updating user data after answering a question, so I need a fast query to give user a better experience in loading the next question.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the columns in your WHERE condition indexed? Change the UPDATE to a SELECT to see how Mysql executes it:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `weakvocab` WHERE `owner` = 'owner_name' AND `vocID` = 'ID_number' AND `type` = 'type_name';
```

and paste the result in here

Comment: the select without explain is fast about 0.2s

Comment: @bn The question wasn't about EXPLAIN's speed but it's results.

Comment: @bn the `EXPLAIN` will show you if you need to add any indexes, like @Mark Byers mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an index on `(owner_name, vocID, type)` so that the record to update can be found faster.

Comment: how can I add index on the, will that affect the existing data?